# remove discount from the cart page

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping-cart, discount

Is there any way to remove **discount price** [NOT THE COUPON FORM] from the **cart page** and adjust the Totals accordingly but should be visible on checkout page ?

Comment: you can hide it using CSS on cart page. if you want to keep thing simple

Comment: but how would you adjust totals ? that should also be without discount price.

Comment: Check this - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/241361/remove-apply-discount-code-from-cart

Comment: Not working. @SairajGadekar

Comment: Can you mention the Magento version and whether it is enterprise or community edition

Comment: It's community edition 2.3.5